# regexp no space

Tags: sql, plsql, regexp-replace, regexp-like

The regexp [[:blank:]] and \s arent they the same.
The below shows 2 different results.

```
select regexp_replace('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner','/','') 
from dual 
where regexp_like(trim('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner'),'[^[[:blank:]]]');
```

The above query returns no rows whereas when i replace blank with [^/s] it returns the row.

Comment: What is the pattern you want to match? For example, `[^x]` matches any character that is not `x`. Do you really want to test whether `'Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner'` contains any character that is not a whitespace character, or do you actually want to check whether it contains any whitespace?

Comment: i am looking to return the string that has no blanks in it . In the example, the string has no blanks so the query should return that row. i used the correct syntax and now i get it.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner','/','') as result
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner'), '[^[:blank:]]');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
Greg94Eric99ChandlerFaulkner

SQL>
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner','/','') as result
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner'), '[[:blank:]]');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
Greg94Eric99ChandlerFaulkner

SQL>
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner','/','') as result
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner'), '[^\s]');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
Greg94Eric99ChandlerFaulkner

SQL>
```

Pick the one you like the most. Besides, if you found what works OK, why don't you simply use it (and forget about the one that doesn't work)? (I guess I know - because of *but WHY???*).

Comment: This might be easier to read without the stray single quotes messing up SO formatting.

Comment: Sorry, @William, but - I don't understand what you are saying. What is messed up? Looks OK to me (reading on my notebook).

Comment: A quoted string starts in the middle of `REGEXP_REPLACE('GREG94/ERIC9` (the first column heading) and so all the quote highlighting is inside out until the middle of the second heading.

Comment: Ah, the **highlighting**! Got it now, thank you, @William; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are using [[:blank:]] instead of [:blank:].
Regular Expression [^ [[:blank:]]] evaluate:

1. ^[[:blank:]] : no character within the list "[, [:blank:]"
2. ] last character to be evaluated.

or you remove the last character ']' which is the one that is not returning records or correct the expression:
[^ [:blank:]]

[^\s] is correct.

Comment: In a regexp \s and the class [:blank:] are NOT the same; \s actually corresponds to the POSIX class [:space:] which is much more inclusive. [:blank:] is space and tab; [:space:] is space, tab, form feed, etc. See [Oracle POSIX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS233) and a [POSIX description](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS233).

Comment: Yes, I do not say otherwise, [: blank:] and \s are different but not because the queries have different results. The queries produce different results because one of them uses a regular expression incorrect for the case.

Comment: You have a space in your character class - `[: blank:]` should be `[:blank:]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a clearer test would be to generate some strings containing various whitespace characters and then use `case` expressions to see whether they match different regexes.

```
with demo (str) as
     ( select ':' from dual union all
       select 'a' from dual union all
       select 'b' from dual union all
       select 'c' from dual union all
       select 'contains'||chr(9)||'tabs' from dual union all
       select 'contains'||chr(10)||chr(13)||'linebreaks' from dual union all
       select 'contains some spaces' from dual
     )
select str
     , case when regexp_like(str,'[:blank:]') then 'Y' end as "[:blank:]"
     , case when regexp_like(str,'[[:blank:]]') then 'Y' end as "[[:blank:]]"
     , case when regexp_like(str,'[[:space:]]') then 'Y' end as "[[:space:]]"
     , case when regexp_like(str,'\s') then 'Y' end as "\s"
from   demo
order by 1;

STR                  [:blank:] [[:blank:]] [[:space:]] \s
-------------------- --------- ----------- ----------- --
:                    Y                                 
a                    Y                                 
b                    Y                                 
c                                                      
contains    tabs     Y                     Y           Y
contains             Y                     Y           Y

linebreaks                                             
contains some spaces Y         Y           Y           Y
```

(I manually edited the result for the row with tabs to align the results, otherwise the tab messes it up and makes it harder to read.)

`[:blank:]` matches any of `:`, `b`, `l`, `a`, `n`, `k`, because a character class is only valid within a `[]` bracket expression.

`[[:blank:]]` only matches spaces.

`[[:space:]]` matches tab, newline, carriage return and space.

`\s` is the same as `[[:space:]]`

As for your example, it is not behaving as you expected in two different ways.

Firstly, `[^[[:blank:]]]` should be `[^[:blank:]]` - that is, the character class `[:blank:]` within a bracketed expression.

Secondly, the corrected syntax still returns a match when there are no blanks because it looks for any character that is not a space, for example the first character `G` is not a space so it matches the expression:

```
regexp_like('Greg94/Eric99Chandler/Faulkner','[^ ]');
```

To identify strings that do not contain any whitespace character, you should use:

```
not regexp_like(str,'\s')
```

or

```
not regexp_like(str, '[[:space:]]')
```